# Magento browse store view when i browse only the sub domain but not the complete store url

Tags: .htaccess, magento, cookies

I have followed some help from a blog and setup magento multistore view in subdomain, and it is working perfectly when i enter `url/?___store=store_name`.

I mean I have setup two store view one is [grabgotech.com](http://grabgotech.com) another one is [magento1.grabgotech.com](http://magento1.grabgotech.com)

For the first time in firefox private window or in google chrome incognito window if I browse grabgotech.com and  magento1.grabgotech.com then the store view is not changing

but if I use the magento store view switcher then it redirects to

`http:&sol;&sol;grabgotech.com/index.php/?&UnderBar;&UnderBar;&UnderBar;store=default&&UnderBar;&UnderBar;&UnderBar;from_store=sudipta_store`

and

`http:&sol;&sol;magento1.grabgotech.com/index.php/?&UnderBar;&UnderBar;&UnderBar;store=sudipta_store&&UnderBar;&UnderBar;&UnderBar;from_store=default`

and switching of store view is working perfectly.

I thought this was because of setting the store view value to cookie, so for that I have also set up cookie domain in admin panel of each store view, but still no luck.

If I browse to  grabgotech.com then I want it to show me the "default" store view, and if I browse only to magento1.grabgotech.com then it should show me the `sudipta_store` view,

I don't want to use `/?___store=&lt;store name>` any more.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this through .htaccess

```
SetEnvIf Host grabgotech\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=default
SetEnvIf Host magento1\.grabgotech\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=sudipta_store
```

This will set MAGE_RUN_CODE to the appropriate store view based on the domain of the request.

Magento reads those variables in index.php and loads the specified store view:

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Comment: Sudipta ,try this answer

Comment: I have already tried the same but not happening. Basically subdomain can't set the store view.

Comment: @sudipta why not? This should work. Are both sites on the same code base?

Comment: @Martin Yes, I have already did this for both site. but still its needs trailing /?___store=<store_view_name> with the sub domain url to open the store view. otherwise if i only browse the sub domain then default store view is opening in google chrome incognito window and in firefox private window.

Comment: @sudipta if you modify index.php to print_r($_SERVER) do you see MAGE_RUN_CODE set?